# webparts suddenly quit working

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, web-part, document-library

Dataview webparts and Document Set webparts have suddenly quit working on both Production and Test farms.

Community references removing KB2844286, but this is not in our environments.

Within the SP (SharePoint) logs, I am seeing:

> Error while executing web part: System.NullReferenceException: Object
>   reference not set to an instance of an object.  at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.SingleDataSource.GetXPathNavigatorInternal()
>   at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.SingleDataSource.GetXPathNavigator() 
>   at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.DataFormWebPart.GetXPathNavigator(String
>   viewPath)  at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.DataFormWebPart.PrepareAndPerformTransform(Boolean
>   bDeferExecuteTransform)

I am also getting webpart errors on document libraries with associated document sets newly created using an existing and proven template.  Existing projects prior to when the webparts failed continue to work with their document set as intended.

> The error in the UI is:  Unable to display this Web Part. To
>   troubleshoot the problem, open this Web page in a Microsoft SharePoint
>   Foundation-compatible HTML editor such as Microsoft SharePoint
>   Designer. If the problem persists, contact your Web server
>   administrator

.

There is no error showing in the web part maintenance page.

> The error in the SP log reflects: Error while executing web part:
>   System.ArgumentException: Value does not fall within the expected
>   range.      at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb.GetWebRelativeUrlFromUrl(String strUrl,
>   Boolean includeQueryString, Boolean canonicalizeUrl)      at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFolder..ctor(SPWeb web, String strUrl, Boolean
>   bServerRel, Guid uniqueId)      at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFolder..ctor(SPWeb web, String strUrl, Boolean
>   bServerRel)      at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.SPDataSourceView.ExecuteSelect(DataSourceSelectArguments
>   selectArguments, String aggregateString, Boolean wantReturn,
>   BaseXsltListWebPart webpart, SPListItem& listItem,
>   SPListItemCollection& listItems, String[]& fieldList)      at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.SingleDataSource.GetXPathNavigatorInternal()
>   at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.SingleDataSource.GetXPathNavigator() 
>   at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.DataFormWebPart.PrepareAndPerformTransform(Boolean
>   bDeferExecuteTransform)

I have researched the servers for recent OS security patches.  There are neither security patches nor recent SP CU updates near to when this issue was reported.

Platform: SP2010 SP1; Windows 2008 SP1; CU May 2015; Browser - IE11 32-bit

Any assistance in this would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RESOLVED: There was an errant certificate entry in MMC (Microsoft Management Console) on one WFE. The other was not affected. When the server administrator resolved the problem, the web parts display consistently.